# Unity hub error opening unity version 2019

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control

After installing unity hub, I had Unity 2017 already installed. Then I downloaded Unity 2019 from the Unity Hub without any extra build support.

Then I made a new project in unity 2019 from the hub. The project does not start. When I open it manually I get the following error message:

> Project does not exist: /Users/user/Desktop

I tried restarting my laptop but the same problem occurs.

What I notice when I make a new project from unity hub of unity 2019
that unity launches in the dock for one millisecond then it disappears. ***Note: I am using a mac***

What I think is that unity is opening then it closes instantly.

Comment: then you need to change the folder in the hub when you made the new project, that folder obviously doesnt exist

Comment: @BugFinder I changed the path to the desktop but the .same problem remains

Comment: did you just remove the /Username?

Comment: @BugFinder It is just crashing I already had other unity 2017 projects in that folder but also after creating a 2019 project in desktop it doesn't open.

Comment: Are you sure it was the same folder or one that looked similar? such as instead of "/Users/user/Desktop" it was "/Users/yousoff/Desktop" ?

Comment: oh no, it was "/Users/user/Desktop" this but the path is not the problem. OH and now the project is not being created at all. What is the problem? I can only create a 2017 project but not 2019's why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196281/discussion-between-youssof-h-and-bugfinder).

Comment: then contact unity support.

Answer (score 2):

This causes when you have multiple instances of unity installed on your system. Try to remove old version and then try to open your project, make sure you have completed removed your old version of unity.

If this does not work then make an empty project with same name and copy the old projects asset folder and replace it in a new project.

Answer (score 1):

> Project does not exist: /Users/user/Desktop

Looks like somehow Unity Hub is trying to open Desktop as a project. 
It looks like a bug.

You can try to press Add button and select project path carefully or to workaround this issue, the -projectPath command line argument could work, in theory it should bypass the Hub. Navigate to Unity's directory and launch it like this: `./Unity -projectPath <path_to_project>`

You should send a bug report to Unity.

Comment: My problem was solved partially by deleting unity 2017 and reinstalling unity hub. Thanks.

Comment: I am happy to hear it :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Unity hub and it worked for me. 
Apparently I did not have the latest version, so I uninstalled the version I had and reinstalled the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a VPN, sometimes that  may be the cause of the problem, try turning it off

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, Whenever I tried with creating any new projects from Unity Hub It is showing me error of Path, Once I tried to Run unity editor separately and create a new project from the editor, My Problem Solved.